# The multi-part identifier 'dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3' could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im having a problem with this :( is this because of my select statement? or any join? derived table? or my CASE syntax?

The error occurs the time I put this CASE syntax: `CASE WHEN dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 = 1 THEN 2`

because before it is just:
`CASE WHEN WorkOrder.DateCreated < (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(dw, 
                                                  dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start) = 2) THEN (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 3 ELSE (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 1 END) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS ScheduleTime`

[image]

```
SELECT        Start, UserDefined3, ItemNo, Name, TotalQtyRequired, PreviouslyCounted, QtyLeftToPick, LocationCode, Location, Rack, QtyInRack, PickQty, CellCode, UDMaterial, UDMaterialSort, ScheduleTimeFROM            (SELECT        dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start, dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemNo, dbo.ItemSpecs.Name, SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.RemainingQty, 0) * ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.TotalQtyPerRoot, 0)) 
                                                AS TotalQtyRequired, ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0) AS PreviouslyCounted, SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.RemainingQty, 0) * ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.TotalQtyPerRoot, 0)) 
                                                - ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0) AS QtyLeftToPick, RackedInventory.LocationCode, RackedInventory.Location, RackedInventory.Rack, ISNULL(RackedInventory.QtyInRack, 0) AS QtyInRack, 
                                                ISNULL(CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.RemainingQty, 0) * ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.TotalQtyPerRoot, 0)) - ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0) 
                                                < RackedInventory.QtyInRack THEN SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.RemainingQty, 0) * ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.TotalQtyPerRoot, 0)) - ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0) 
                                                ELSE RackedInventory.QtyInRack END, 0) AS PickQty, dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.CellCode, dbo.ItemSpecs.Userdefined2 AS UDMaterial, CASE WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.Userdefined2 IN ('Foam', 'Wood', 
                                                'Plastic Inner', 'Rubber') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS UDMaterialSort, CASE WHEN dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 = 1 THEN 2 WHEN WorkOrder.DateCreated < (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(dw, 
                                                dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start) = 2) THEN (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 3 ELSE (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 1 END) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS ScheduleTime
                      FROM            dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress INNER JOIN
                                                dbo.OpenCalendarDaysTable AS OpenCalendarDays ON dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start BETWEEN OpenCalendarDays.CalendarDateForwardRangeStart AND 
                                                OpenCalendarDays.CalendarDateForwardRangeEnd AND OpenCalendarDays.CalendarLinkID IS NULL INNER JOIN
                                                dbo.OpenCalendarDaysTable AS PriorOpenCalendarDays ON OpenCalendarDays.CalendarOpenDayID = PriorOpenCalendarDays.CalendarOpenDayID + 1 AND OpenCalendarDays.CalendarLinkID IS NULL 
                                                INNER JOIN
                                                dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc ON dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.ItemSpecID = dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.RootItemSpecID INNER JOIN
                                                dbo.ItemSpecs ON dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.ChildItemSpecID = dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemSpecID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                dbo.WorkOrder ON dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.WorkOrderID = dbo.WorkOrder.WorkOrderID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    (SELECT        InventoryByLocation.ItemID, InventoryByLocation.ItemNo, InventoryByLocation.ItemDescription, InventoryByLocation.LocationCode, InventoryByLocation.Location, InventoryByLocation.Rack, 
                                                                                InventoryByLocation.QtyInRack, SUM(PreviouslyCounted.QtyInRack) AS PreviouslyCounted
                                                      FROM            (SELECT        Rack, SUM(ISNULL(QtyToStock, ' ')) AS QtyInRack, ItemID, ItemSpecID, LocationID
                                                                                FROM            dbo.InventoryItems WITH (NOLOCK)
                                                                                GROUP BY ItemID, ItemSpecID, LocationID, Rack) AS PreviouslyCounted RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                    (SELECT        Items_1.ItemNo, Items_1.Name AS ItemDescription, Locations_1.LocationCode, Locations_1.DescriptionMed AS Location, InventoryItems_1.Rack, 
                                                                                                                SUM(dbo.Val(ISNULL(InventoryItems_1.QtyToStock, ''))) AS QtyInRack, UOMs_1.UOMCode AS StockUOM, InventoryItems_1.ItemID, InventoryItems_1.ItemSpecID, 
                                                                                                                Locations_1.LocationID
                                                                                      FROM            dbo.Items AS Items_1 WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                                                                                                dbo.Locations AS Locations_1 WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN
                                                                                                                dbo.InventoryItems AS InventoryItems_1 WITH (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                                                dbo.UOMs AS UOMs_1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON InventoryItems_1.StockUOMID = UOMs_1.UOMID ON Locations_1.LocationID = InventoryItems_1.LocationID ON 
                                                                                                                Items_1.ItemID = InventoryItems_1.ItemID
                                                                                      WHERE        (Locations_1.LocationID = 7)
                                                                                      GROUP BY Locations_1.LocationCode, Items_1.ItemNo, Locations_1.DescriptionMed, Items_1.Name, UOMs_1.UOMCode, InventoryItems_1.ItemID, InventoryItems_1.ItemSpecID, 
                                                                                                                Locations_1.LocationID, InventoryItems_1.Rack
                                                                                      HAVING         (SUM(dbo.Val(ISNULL(InventoryItems_1.QtyToStock, ''))) > 0)) AS InventoryByLocation ON PreviouslyCounted.Rack < InventoryByLocation.Rack AND 
                                                                                PreviouslyCounted.LocationID = InventoryByLocation.LocationID AND PreviouslyCounted.ItemID = InventoryByLocation.ItemID
                                                      GROUP BY InventoryByLocation.ItemNo, InventoryByLocation.ItemDescription, InventoryByLocation.LocationCode, InventoryByLocation.Location, InventoryByLocation.Rack, InventoryByLocation.QtyInRack, 
                                                                                InventoryByLocation.ItemID) AS RackedInventory ON dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemID = RackedInventory.ItemID
                      WHERE        (dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.ExcludeFromFiniteScheduling = 0) AND (ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecs.Userdefined2, '') <> 'Covering') AND (dbo.ItemSpecs.InventoryTrackingID > 1)
                      GROUP BY dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start, dbo.ItemSpecs.ItemNo, dbo.ItemSpecs.Name, RackedInventory.Rack, ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0), RackedInventory.Location, 
                                                RackedInventory.LocationCode, dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.CellCode, dbo.ItemSpecs.Userdefined2, 
                                                CASE WHEN dbo.AdditionalInfo.UserDefined3 = 1 THEN 2 WHEN WorkOrder.DateCreated < (CASE WHEN (DATEPART(dw, dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start) = 2) THEN (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) 
                                                - 3 ELSE (ToBeScheduled_InProgress.Start + 0.625) - 1 END) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, RackedInventory.QtyInRack
                      HAVING         (SUM(ISNULL(dbo.ToBeScheduled_InProgress.RemainingQty, 0) * ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecFullStruc.TotalQtyPerRoot, 0)) - ISNULL(RackedInventory.PreviouslyCounted, 0) > 0)) AS _RackSort_Lean_AMPM ORDER BY Start, LocationCode, Rack
```

Comment: If the search in my browser didn't deceive me (that query is horrible to read), you're not having `dbo.AdditionalInfo` targeted in any `FROM`, `JOIN` etc.. And you cannot address a column of a table that isn't mentioned in the query. So add `dbo.AdditionalInfo` appropriately to fix the error.

Comment: that's my challenge because this query is not my query:( I am just modifying an old one that's why it's really a challenge for me.

Comment: @TrishFernandez you need to join AdditionalInfo table with one of the tables at from

Comment: it worked now. thank you both for your suggestions. :)